# Apply a function over all combinations of arguments (output as list)

Tags: r, apply

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25911463) is almost what I need, but do not worked to my case.
Here is what I have tried:

```
comb_apply <- function(f,...){
  exp <- expand.grid(...,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  apply(exp,1,function(x) do.call(f,x))
}

#--- Testing Code
l1 <- list("val1","val2")
l2 <- list(2,3)

testFunc<-function(x,y){
  list(x,y)
}

#--- Executing Test Code
comb_apply(testFunc,l1,l2)
comb_apply(paste,l1,l2)
```

It works for `paste` example, but I get the message: `Error in (function (x, y)  : unused arguments (Var1 = "val1", Var2 = 2)` when I try my `testFunc`.

My expectation is to get as result:

```
list(list("val1",2),list("val1",3),list("val2",2),list("val2",3))
```

### Motivation

I came from [Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/), on which perform this operation is as simple as:

```
l1 = {"val1", "val2"}
l2 = {2, 3}
testFunc = {#1, #2} &
Outer[testFunc, l1, l2]
```

How can I do it in `R`?

Comment: `R` has an `?outer` function.

Comment: @sgibb I need a generic case, where more then 2 lists are possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some try and error attempts, I found a solution.

In order to make `comb_apply` to work, I needed to `unname` each exp value before use it. Here is the code:

```
comb_apply <- function(f,...){
  exp <- expand.grid(...,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  apply(exp,1,function(x) do.call(f,unname(x)))
}
```

Now, executing `str(comb_apply(testFunc,l1,l2))` I get the desired result, without change `testFunc`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `mapply` or `plyr::mlply` for this,

```
comb_apply <- function(f,..., MoreArgs=list()){
  exp <- unname(expand.grid(...,stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
  do.call(mapply, c(list(FUN=f, SIMPLIFY=FALSE, MoreArgs=MoreArgs), exp))
}
```