# Vectorized approach for the following task

Tags: r, dplyr, vectorization, tidyverse

The following code works, but as expected, it takes ages to execute for large vectors.

What would be the vectorised way to accomplish the same task:

```
x <- seq(0,10,0.01)
y <- seq(0,10,0.01)
df <- data.frame(vector1 = rnorm(10000), vector2 = rnorm(10000), vector3 = rnorm(10000))


m.out <- matrix(nrow=length(x),ncol = length(y))

a <- df$vector1
b <- df$vector2
c <- df$vector3

for (i in 1:length(x)){
  for(j in 1:length(y)){
    m.out[i,j] <- cor((x[i]*a + y[j]*b),c,use="complete.obs",method = "pearson")
  }
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: Your example is not working, can you fix it? It would be nice to have `seed`  and data size too.

Comment: Where is `df`??

Comment: @PoGibas where is a `seed` needed?

Comment: There's no `df`, how is it generated? How big is it?

Comment: This [H E R E](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30686904/apply-a-function-over-all-combinations-of-arguments-output-as-list) seems to be what you're after???

Answer (score 0):

Please see vectorized version below, you can use `mapply` and `expand.grid`. To return to wide dataset format you can use `dcast` of `reshape2` package (however it still takes some time):

```
set.seed(123)
x <- seq(0, 10, 0.01)
y <- seq(0, 10, 0.01)

# simulation
df <- data.frame(vector1 = rnorm(length(x)), vector2 = rnorm(length(x)), vector3 = rnorm(length(x)))
a <- df$vector1
b <- df$vector2
c <- df$vector3

v <- expand.grid(x, y)
v$out <- mapply(function(n, m) cor(n * a + m * b, c, use = "complete.obs", method = "pearson"), v[, 1], v[, 2])
library(reshape2)
z <- dcast(v, Var1 ~ Var2)
rownames(z) <- z$Var1
z <- z[, -1]
head(z[, 1:5])
```

Output:

```
               0          0.01          0.02          0.03          0.04
0             NA  0.0140699293  0.0140699293  0.0140699293  0.0140699293
0.01 -0.01383734  0.0003350528  0.0065542508  0.0090938390  0.0103897953
0.02 -0.01383734 -0.0059841841  0.0003350528  0.0042062076  0.0065542508
0.03 -0.01383734 -0.0086178379 -0.0035752709  0.0003350528  0.0031310581
0.04 -0.01383734 -0.0099713568 -0.0059841841 -0.0024814273  0.0003350528
0.05 -0.01383734 -0.0107798236 -0.0075458061 -0.0045052606 -0.0018627055
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Artem; however, after some bench marking, my original approach takes roughly the same amount of time than your version. Cheers